# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Java Backend with CrossOrigin("*") annotation

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I know that there are a lot of questions regarding this topic, but after a few hours of trying multiple fixes I haven't been able to make it work.

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/bag")
public class RestBagController {
```

My controller currently accepts any cross origin requests.

The issue seems to be with this particular method that consumes multipart/form-data

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data", path = {"/image"})
public ResponseEntity<?> saveImages(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) {
```

Finally, my ajax request

```js
 var blobFile = $("#serialcodefile").prop('files')[0];
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("serialcodefile", blobFile, "serialCode");
        

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/bag/image",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    success: onSuccess,
});
```

My backend is hosted in localhost:8080 and the frontend on localhost:5501.

Also I'm not sure if relevant, but once I press the submit button on the form, I make 2 POST requests.

- To: "http://localhost:8080/api/bag/"
- To:"http://localhost:8080/api/bag/image"

Comment: `localhost` is notorious for causing problems with different-port setups. Please start by confirming in your browser's Network tab what traffic you have, including OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Hosting the website online (in heroku) so I could get out of localhost didnt prove to be any different unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

From jquery docs - `contentType` (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')

Here is the link to docs - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Search for ContentType here.

Can you try by removing `headers` and instead add `ContentType:false`.
Hope this works!!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/bag/image",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    ContentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    success: onSuccess,
});
```

Comment: @Ricardo Did you get chance to try this?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Chrome try to disable CORS like [there](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/) or run in another browser, because Chrome has built-in protection from this.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion! Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue!

Comment: Ah, these pesky security features, just disable them all, makes life a lot easier ... and unsafer!